# HTML UTF8 Arabic text drift and is not displayed inline

Tags: html, utf-8, arabic, utf

When i display Arabic UTF8 text, the text drift and collude with the line below.

I Can't display the image (You need at least 10 reputation to post images ...) But the arabic text seems drifting even here !

My Header :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

My arabic text :

```
    وَإِذِ اسْتَسْقَىٰ مُوسَىٰ لِقَوْمِهِ فَقُلْنَا اضْرِبْ بِعَصَاكَ الْحَجَرَ ۖ فَانْفَجَرَتْ مِنْهُ اثْنَتَا عَشْرَةَ عَيْنًا ۖ قَدْ عَلِمَ كُلُّ أُنَاسٍ مَشْرَبَهُمْ ۖ كُلُوا وَاشْرَبُوا مِنْ رِزْقِ اللَّهِ وَلَا تَعْثَوْا فِي الْأَرْضِ مُفْسِدِينَ
```

Comment: Have You checked your browser encoding ?

Comment: Farshad jan, It seems you're onto something, Firefox and safari display it perfectly inline, the problem seems to be from chrome.

Comment: My browser encoding is set on UTF-8 and when I set it on anything else it become gibberish.

Comment: What's even stranger is that here on stackoverflow, when I refresh this page the text is at first not inline, but move and come inline !

Comment: your code is ok. I have checked in firefox 31 and chrome 36. here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/xvpdcosu/1/) of your code

Comment: Can it come from my CSS ? In the jsfiddle you sent me, the Result is good and inline, but in the source HTML Code panel the arabix is drifting and not inline, is it the same for you ? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: May be Css or inline styles causes the bug for show result. check your css file and inline styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug between arabic UTF8 text and google Chrome with some fonts like helvetica, helvetica neue, Georgia, the arabic text drift and doesn't stay inline. 
Changing the font to arial fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First Check your browser Encoding (must be `unicode` and same as your page encoding)

Second check your page `properties` > `encoding` with `dreamweaver` or some other programs.

Your code works correctly
here is [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/xvpdcosu/1/) of your code

Comment: On JSFIDDLE the arabic is displayed correctly inline on the "result" panel. But on the HTML Panel the arabic isn't inline. Is it the same for you ?

Comment: @midomy put url of your online code , I'll check it

Comment: Add `line-height:50px;` to `skeleton.css` line 29 for class `.container .column, .container .columns` this code preventing text overlap

Comment: Thanks Farshad Jan, it's a good workaround but the problem seems to come from the font. Google Chrome doesn't display well arabic in Helvetica and georgia, but arial work fine ! Thanks a lot, your help was very valuable.